# What is the name of the plastic cover of books and magazines?

Tags: word-request

When buying books in books-shop, we see sometimes a transparent cover which covers the book hermetically as a sign that it's new and nobody used or opened it. What is the name of this cover in English? (how to name it?) Can I say simply cover and everybody will understand What I'm talking about?

Comment: [Similar question](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/128250/187797).

Comment: Except, Ganesh, that I don't think *Shrink-wrapped* is the be-all, end all-term. For magazines especially, *plastic cover* itself  seems a possibly more apt and more used term.

Answer (score 17):

Don't confuse the clear wrapping with the **[dust jacket](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dust_jacket)** that's on a hardcover book. For most people, "cover" will mean the same thing as dust jacket.

I think what you're describing is clear plastic **[shrinkwrap](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/shrinkwrap)**.

> A protective wrapping made from clear plastic film that is shrunk onto an object by heat

EDIT
The loose plastic covering that a magazine comes in might better be called a **sleeve** or a **[mailer](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mailer)**, since it's not shrunk tightly onto the magazine inside.

Comment: But see [my comment](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/104085/what-is-the-name-of-the-plastic-cover-of-books-and-magazines#comment206286_104085).

Answer (score 0):

**Cellophane** is a thin, transparent sheet made of regenerated cellulose. Its low permeability to air, oils, greases, bacteria, and water makes it useful for food packaging. --from wikipedea

Comment: Welcome to ELL. Thank you for your contribution, but it doesn't directly answer the OP's question. Could you update your answer to say that a layer of material of this type covering a book would be called a **cellophane wrapper**?

Comment: @JavaLatte If you think you can improve an answer, submit an edit.

Comment: @tjt263, If we encourage and advise new contributors, they will continue to give interesting answers: if we simply change their answers, they may be discouraged.

Comment: More likely they will either; be unaware, be thankful, or be mildly frustrated and roll it back. I am new; this is my experience.

Answer (score -2):

Since paper deteriorates over time, proper protection can be critical especially for older books.  Many sacred texts on parchment or similar do not allow people to touch the paper as the oil from the hands can also cause deterioration to the paper.  In religious circles, rarely is plastic used to protect the books, but in rare occurences when it is used, this protector is called a "Wearsie Bind"

Comment: Thank you for your answer and welcome to ELL. Please review our [**tour**](http://ell.stackexchange.com/tour) and [**Help Center**](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help) pages. (This is an interesting answer, even if not what the question refers to. "Wearsie neck" is sometimes used to refer to the posture problem otherwise called "scholar's neck.") We hope you'll answer more questions and ask some of your own.